# Как добавить новое значение для manytomanyfiled при заполнении формы в django?

Tags: python, django, forms

Здравствуйте.При заполнении формы для объекта, необходимо заполнить поле с множественной связью.Соответственно, мне на страничке формы предлагается стандартный метод заполнения - существующие значения для этого поля в столбик. Вопрос: как мне не выбирать из существующих, а иметь возможность добавить новое значение?

Comment: покажите код из моделей в `amin.py`, скорее всего значение заголовка стоит в `default` модели, а у `slugfield` его нет

Comment: Спасибо, решение было найдено самостоятельно :)